# JSP or Spring MVC controller display same info several times

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have controller which adds Computer assigned to User by admin. User can have several assigned Computers and it is implemented through Spring MVC Multiple Selection. But I’ve little issue with displaying of info after updating. It shows as many users in *List of users* as many computers were assigned. I think problem not in JSP and debuggers shows nothing so I’ll  very appreciate your help.

[image]

Here is my **AdminUserUpdateController.java**

```
@Controller
public class AdminUserUpdateController {


    @InitBinder("userForm")
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(updateValidator);

        binder.registerCustomEditor(Set.class, "computers", new CustomCollectionEditor(Set.class) {

            @Override
            protected Object convertElement(Object element) {
                String pcName = null;

                if (element instanceof String && !((String) element).equals("")) {
                    try {
                        pcName = (String) element;
                        Set<Computer> computerSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
                        computerSet.add(computerService.getComputerByName(pcName));
                        new UserForm().setComputers(computerSet);

                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        logger.info("Error in element");
                        logger.info("Element was " + ((String) element));
                    }
                } 
                return pcName != null ? computerService.getComputerByName(pcName) : null;
            }
        });
    }

  ...............

    @RequestMapping(value = "/adminEdit/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String updateView(@PathVariable("userId") Integer userId,
                             UserForm userForm,
                             ModelMap model) {
        userForm.setUser(userService.getUserById(userId));
        model.addAttribute("userForm", userForm);
        model.addAttribute("computers", computerService.getAllComputers());            
        return "adminUserUpdate";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "adminEdit.do/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView updateUserProcess(@ModelAttribute(value = "userForm")
                                          UserForm userForm,
                                          @PathVariable("userId") Integer userId,
                                          BindingResult result, Model model) {
        User user = userService.getUserById(userId);
        model.addAttribute("computers", computerService.getAllComputers());
        model.addAttribute("userForm", userForm);
        updateValidator.validate(userForm, result);    

        return updatingUser(user, model, userForm);
    }

    private ModelAndView updatingUser(User user, Model model,
                                      UserForm userForm) {
        if (isEmailExists(userForm, user)) {                
            model.addAttribute("errorMsg", "Email is already in use!");
            return new ModelAndView("adminUserUpdate");
        }
        fillForm(userForm, user);
        user = userForm.getUser();
        userService.updateUser(user);           
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/adminPage", "user", user);
    }

    private void fillForm(UserForm userForm, User user) {
        userForm.setUserId(user.getUserId());
        userForm.setLogin(user.getLogin());
        userForm.setRegDate(user.getRegDate());
//        userForm.setComputers(computer);
        userForm.setRole(roleService.findByName(user.getRole().getRoleName()));
    }
   }
```

And here it is my JSP

```
<!--BEGIN OF USERS TABLE-->
        <div align="center">
            <table border=1>
                <thead align="center">
                <tr>
                    <th>User Id</th>
                    <th>Login</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Regsiter Date</th>
                    <th>PC Assigned</th>
                    <th colspan=2>Action</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody align="center">
                <tr>
                    <c:forEach items="${members}" var="user">
                    <td><c:out value="${user.userId}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.login}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.name}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.password}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.email}"/></td>
                    <td><fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" value="${user.regDate}"/></td>
                    <td>
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${user.computers!= null && !user.computers['empty']}">
                                <c:forEach items="${user.computers}" var="comp">
                                    <c:out value="${comp.pcName}"/>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                <p class="h3_error">No PC Assigned</p>
                            </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="${app}/adminEdit/${user.userId}">Update</a></td>                          
                    <td><a href="${app}delete?userId=${user.userId}">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br>

        </div>
        <!--END OF USERS TABLE-->
```

Comment: did you check your database first?

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) please, I'm pretty sure your `AdminUserUpdateController` class could be simplified for more readability.

Comment: Yes, it is only one record in the DB.

Comment: And ... what about showing the controller that shows the table, because I do not think it is the one you show.

Comment: I've done as short as I can. Because I don't know what part of code can be reason of issue.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta: I don't think that problem in this controller, because it is very simple.
      `@RequestMapping(value = "/adminPage", method =RequestMethod.GET)
      private ModelAndView adminPage(Model model) {
      model.addAttribute("computers",     computerService.getAllComputers());
        return new ModelAndView("administration", "members", userService.getAllUsers());
    }`

Comment: It is not there but not so far : I suspect a problem in `userService.getAllUsers())` or in the request that populates it. Can you show that ?

Comment: In the **service**  layer:
       `Override
        public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userDao.getAllUsers(); 
        }`

In DAO layer:
    `Override
    Transactional
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return currentSession().createCriteria(User.class).list();
    }`